# How can I make divs collide?

Tags: html, css

```css
#left{
    border: dotted 1px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
#right{
    border: dotted 1px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
#mid{
    border: groove 1px blue;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</body>
```

I want this middle div to be squished by the other two ones at the sides if page shrinks. But left one is not colliding with the middle ones borders. And also right one is at the bottom.
How can I do this?
[image]

This is how ı want it to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're missing out some styles.

You simply need to make the body element a flex, by adding: `body {display: flex;}`

So your code becomes this:

```css
body{
    display: flex;
}
#left{
    border: dotted 1px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
#right{
    border: dotted 1px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
#mid{
    border: groove 1px blue;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: adding this into my code makes the #right and #left to shrink too. I want them to stay as  set them. And also this makes the #mid look like a line in the middle.

Comment: After messing with it i finally solved it. That display: flex helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the `body` style as `display: flex`. That will solve the problem of the `#right` at the bottom.

From what I understand about the squish, `#right` and `#left` are fixed and `#mid` grows and shrinks according the space availability.

You may achieve this effect setting a `min-width` for `#right` and `#left`, while setting `flex: flex-growth flex-shrink` of `#mid`. If, additionally, you want to have space between the `divs` when the screen is large, you can set `max-width` for `#mid` as well.

Note: I recommend removing the `float` properties.

Here's an example.

[image: Edit snowy-dawn-mtm97m]

Comment: Actually this is not what ı meant. I added a picture about it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I've edited the answer to accomplish what the image shows. Take a look!